# Positioning nodes and calculate edges coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, edge, relative

I am trying to draw a flowchart with tikz, but I have 2 problems.

The first one is about the positioning of (action5). I want that node to be left (action4) and below (test1). In my code, the node is not align with (test1).

The second problem is about the positioning of the edge in red from (wait1).
I would like the edge to touch the edge between (test1) and (action4).

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows,shapes,shapes.arrows,trees,calc}

\tikzset{
wait/.style={circle, draw=black, text centered, anchor=north, text=black, font=\scriptsize},
end/.style={draw=none, fill=none, text centered, anchor=north}
wait/.style={circle,draw=black,text centered,anchor=north,text=black,font=\scriptsize},
decision/.style={diamond,draw=black,    inner sep=0.18cm,text centered,anchor=north,text=black},
action/.style={ regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,inner sep=0.2cm,draw=black,text centered,anchor=north,text=black},
foreach/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw=black,text centered,anchor=north,text=black},
endforeach/.style={ foreach,shape border rotate=180}        
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h] 
\begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]

        \node (start) [end] {Begin $P_{I2-1}(partial, firstAppNode)$};
        \node (action1) [action,below=0.5 of start,label=0:{Init graph matching algorithm \\ (partial, firstAppNode)}] {};  
        \node (action2) [action, below=1 of action1, label=0:{Compute next partial projection}] {};
        \node (test1) [decision, below=0.5 of action2] {};
        \node (foreach1) [foreach, below right = 0.5 and 4 of test1,label=0:{ForEach $appNeighbour$ of $firstAppNode$}] {};
        \node (foreach2) [foreach, below right = 1 and 1 of foreach1,label=180:{ForEach $neighbour$}] {};
        \node (action3) [action,below=1 of foreach2,label=180:{Send message \\ to neighbour \\ request(projection, ...)}] {};
        \node (wait1) [wait, below=1 of action3] {$\mathcal{W}$};
        \node (endforeach2) [endforeach, below=0.5 of wait1] {};
        \node (endforeach1) [endforeach, below left=0.5 and 1 of endforeach2] {};
        \node (action4) [action, below=0.5 of endforeach1, label=0:{Send message to A \\ response(partial)}] {};
        \node (action5) [action, left=4 of action4, label=0:{Send message to A \\ response(projection)}] {}; %
        \node (action6) [action, left=1 of action5, label=180:{Send message to A \\ response(none)}] {};
        \node (end1) [end, below=0.5 of action4] {End ok};
        \node (end2) [end, below=0.5 of action5] {End ok};
        \node (end3) [end, below=0.5 of action6] {End ok};

        \draw[->] (start)--(action1);
        \draw[->] (action1)--(action2);
        \draw[->] (action2)--(test1);
        \draw[->,red] (test1)--(action5) node[pos=0.04,left] {complete};
        \draw[->] (test1)-|(action6) node[pos=0.15,above] {fail};
        \draw[->] (test1)-|(foreach1) node[pos=0.15,above] {projection};
        \draw[->] (foreach1)|-($(foreach1)!0.5!(foreach2)$)-|(foreach2);
        \draw[->] (foreach2)--(action3);
        \draw[->] (action3)--(wait1);
        \draw[->] (wait1)--(endforeach2) node[pos=0.3,right] {response(none)};
        \coordinate[shift={(0,1)}] (wait1endforeach1) at (endforeach1.north);
        \draw[->] (wait1)--(wait1endforeach1)--(endforeach1) node[pos=0.2,left] {response(partial)};
        \coordinate[shift={(-5,0)}] (wait1action4) at (wait1.west);
        \draw[->,red] (wait1)--(wait1action4) node[pos=0.3,above] {response(complete)};
        \draw[->] (endforeach1)--(action4);
        \draw[->] (action4)--(end1);
        \draw[->] (action5)--(end2);
        \draw[->] (action6)--(end3);

        \coordinate[shift={(-3,0)}] (linkforeach1) at (foreach1.south);
        \draw[dashed] (foreach1) -| (linkforeach1) |- (endforeach1) ;   
        \coordinate[shift={(3,0)}] (linkforeach2) at (foreach2.south);
        \draw[dashed] (foreach2) -| (linkforeach2) |- (endforeach2) ;   

        \coordinate[shift={(5.5,-0.5)}] (foreach2action2) at (endforeach2.south);
        \draw[->] (endforeach2) |- (foreach2action2) |- ($(action1)!0.5!(action2)$) ;   


        \node[above,shift=({0,-0.1cm})] at(start.north) {\textbf{Compute application projection}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please complete your code snipped that we can copy it to our computers and test it. So far I found undefined node styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

```
\node (action5) [action, label=0:{Send message to A \\ response(projection)}] at (action4 -| test1){}; %
```

Second question:

```
\draw[->,red] (wait1)--($(test1)!(wait1)!(action5)$) node[pos=0.3,above] {response(complete)};
```

---

Please don't just add code that doesn't compile (missing lots of styles and libraries). Not only it is super boring to read the code but also you get answers that are not tested.

Comment: Thanks, it works !
I modify the first tip in 
`\node (action5) [action, label=0:{Send message to A \\ response(projection)}] at (action4.north -| test1){};`